# clang-format treats template and function arguments differently

Tags: c++, clang-format

Running clang-format with `-style=LLVM`, I get results like

```
fooooooooooooooooob<
i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i,
bar<i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i>>();

foooooooooooooooobb(i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i,
                    baz(i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i,
                        i, i, i, i, i))();
```

Note that the second and third examples only differ in that one uses angle brackets `<>` and the other uses parentheses `()`. How do I get the example with angle brackets to align like the example with parentheses?  I have tried many of the options at

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

but I have not been able to make it work.

Comment: Does the code actually compile?

Comment: It is a valid C++ snippet.  My original example `#include`'s header files and will compile.  This simplified snippet will not, but clang-format never reads header files.

Comment: My clang-format 5 gives me [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/057c77d779c2914a) for the original snippet and [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3aeb90b51bd9a7c3) for a little bit more sane snippet using the LLVM style.

Comment: I must have had ContinuationIndentWidth set to 0.  In any event, your first snippet shows the same problem of the angle brackets and parentheses behaving differently. I would like them to behave the same.The second one is inside a nested block which makes clang-format treat them the same.